# htaccess redirect to https exclude one url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, https

I know its duplicate and there are a lot of answers in google, but nothing works for me, yet.
I'm not strong or even average with apache, but I'd like to exclude one url that starts from `/test/` from HTTPS redirect.

```
//redirect not working
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/(/test/)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} https
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/(/test/)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R,L]

//infinity loop
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} !on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/(test)
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} =on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/test)
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]

//thats my first HTTPS redirect, tried to add RewriteCond to exclude test, but nothing works
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/test/ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

I'd appreciate for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Found an answer by myself

```
    # force https:// for all except some selected URLs    
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/test/ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

    # force http:// for selected URLs
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /test/ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```